# wrapping circular black frame for video - What is this effect called?

Tags: post-production

when using [magic bullet looks](http://www.redgiant.com/products/all/magic-bullet-looks/) on a video it applies - alongside color corrections and such - a frame, some sort of wrapping mask thingy - a black outline for the video the gives the center a bit more focus. You can see it pretty clearly here:

[image]

I want a png of that. Just that. I am searching Google for all kinds of word combinations but nothing. **What is this effect called??**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it's a [vignette](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vignetting).
Here's a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yHdJoUxJfyk) on how to do it.

If you add a black solid layer to a comp, then feather the edges, and invert the mask, you'll get the basic effect.  Beyond that, some people used coloured solids (e.g. just off-black in one colour or another).  You can also apply a blur or defocus effect towards the edges of the image, if that's the look you're going for.